# How to send an object to php using retrofit 2?

Tags: java, php, android, pdo, retrofit

I'm refactoring my app to use `Retrofit 2`, I was able to make all my `GET requests` fine, but I can't understand how to make `POST requests`.

I've got this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $e here

I know what that exception means, is pretty straightforward. My problem is that I'm not able to change my PHP file to expect Strings or, to change the java class to send an object.

I've got very little understanding of PHP, so I prefer change my java class. 
What it came to my mind was instead of send my java `pojo` class, I could make a `JSONObject` and send it to PHP.

However, I'm not very confident of the PHP file, or the approach I thought of. I would like to tell me if it would be a possible solution or if there is something wrong in the PHP code, that's why is not currently working.

Here are the classes:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

$db = new DB_CONNECT();
$dbh = $db->connect(); // here you get the connection

$name = $_POST['name'];
$breed = $_POST['breed'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$pictures = $_POST['pictures'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$locality = $_POST['locality'];
$userid = $_POST['userid'];

$query = "INSERT INTO lost_pets (name, breed, type, description, pictures, location,locality, userid) VALUES('$name', '$breed', '$type', '$description', '$pictures', '$location', '$locality','$userid')";

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);


$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':breed', $breed, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':pictures', $pictures, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $location, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':locality', $locality, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$dbh =  $stmt->execute(array(":name"=>$name,":breed"=>$breed,":type"=>$type,":description"=>$description,
        ":pictures"=>$pictures,":location"=>$location, ":locality"=>$locality, ":userid"=>$userid));

?>
```

Java Interface:

```
@POST("post_lost_pet.php")
Call<Lost> postLost(@Body Lost lost);
```

postLost method:

```
public void postLost(Lost pet, final IClient client){
    Call<Lost> call = retrofitInit().postLost(pet);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Lost>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Lost> call, Response<Lost> response) {
            System.out.println(response.raw());
            client.lostCallback();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Lost> call, Throwable t) {
            client.lostFailure(t.toString());
        }
    });
```

POJO:

```
public class Lost extends Pet {

public Lost(String name, String breed, String type, String description, String pictures, String location, String locality, String userid) {
    super(name, breed, type, pictures, description, location, locality, userid);
}

public void setLocality(String locality){
    super.setLocality(locality);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    super.setName(name);
}
}
```

Comment: The error message indicates that your PHP code did not return a valid JSON object. Since you're not outputting anything, my guess is that you're getting an error message or that Retrofit expects at least some data to be returned (and not the text 'null' or similar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it replacing the parameters in the java interface, in the retrofit call method:

```
@POST("post_lost_pet.php")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Lost> postLost(@Field("name") String name, @Field("breed") String breed, @Field("type") String type,
                    @Field("pictures") String pictures, @Field("description") String description, @Field("location") String location,
                    @Field("locality") String locality, @Field("userid") String userid);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are expecting a response from the sever, but you are not giving any response from the php file.

In you PHP file add this to the end,

```
$arr = array('response' => 'success');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

this will give response after your query is executed.
Then change the expected response in your interface,

```
@POST("post_lost_pet.php")
Call<MyResponse> postLost(@Body Lost lost);
```

Your response class will look something like this,

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MyResponse implements Parcelable {
    private String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(String response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    protected MyResponse(Parcel in) {
        response = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(response);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<MyResponse> CREATOR = new Creator<MyResponse>() {
        @Override
        public MyResponse createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MyResponse(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MyResponse[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MyResponse[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I'm getting the same error. onResponse never executes. Thanks for your help.